# Get element by a word it contains

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to get an element by its content(a word it contains?)

For example, get all the elements with the letter "F," and put it in a array of elements

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommand you to use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) for these kind of DOM elements searching.
Then you can use this:

```
var foos = $("div:contains('foo')" )
```

will make an array with all divs containing the word 'foo'.

Comment: Only thing to bear in mind with this is it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

One fairly easy way is to select the elements you're interested in and then use 'filter' to look at the `innerText`. You can make this case insensitive with `toLowerCase`

```js
var result = $('div').filter( (i,e) => e.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf("f")>-1);
console.log("Items with 'F':",result.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Forest</div>
<div>Fortnight</div>
<div>Trees</div>
<div>Africa</div>
```

The simpler way is using `:contains('F')` as a selector - but that is always case sensitive (which may be fine for your case).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) as a selector. For example, to filter all divs of a special class that also contains your text, you can use $("div.myclass:contains('searched text')")

Answer (score 0):

I think you can "bruteforce" it by iterating all DOM items. e.g.:

```
let arrayDom = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("*"));
       arrayDom.forEach(element => {
           if (element.innerHTML.contains('F')){
               // Do something
           }
       })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the best solution I could find. I had a short problem though, when you said getElementsByTagName("*"), I wanted to get all elements by all tag names.can I write something like this?                                            `document.getElementsByTagNam("div")`      Please let me know a solution, because this way doesn't really work. I tried querySelectorAll and it still doesn't work. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Actually, I got it to work. I tried a slightly different method. Yet, you helped a lot. Thanks!